# Проблема с позиционированием 100vh в мобильном браузере Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Есть блок с раскрытым меню. Наблюдаю проблему в мобильном браузере **Chrome**: нижний блок с языком скрыт за экраном. В других браузерах такого бага не наблюдаю, нижняя панель прилеплена четко внизу.

Код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: 'Futura PT', sans-serif;
  color: #515151;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}

p,
div,
li {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.header {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(103, 87, 156, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 60px;
}

.header.unlogged {
  height: unset;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  .header {
    background-color: #F4F5F9;
    height: 84px;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .header.noMiddle {
    height: unset;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header {
    height: unset;
  }
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container.open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box p {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box ul a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box ul a:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box .logout {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box .logout:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts>a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts>a:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .albel {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #C4C4C4;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang ul li {
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang ul li.current-language a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang ul li.current-language a span {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #515151;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header.logged .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .lang ul li a span {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #67579C;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
}

.header.unlogged {
  height: unset;
}

.header.unlogged .languages {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .menu-container-header {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  color: #515151;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.header.unlogged .mob-menu-container .menu-container-header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 9px 8px 8px 20px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container.open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 11;
}

.header.unlogged .mob-menu-container .content-container {
  top: 40px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .mmenu-heading {
  background: #F4F5F9;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  color: #515151;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box p {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box ul li {
  padding: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box ul a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box ul a:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box .logout {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box .logout:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box.contacts>a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #67579C;
  transition: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box.contacts>a:hover {
  color: #59C2A4;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .box.contacts .albel {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #C4C4C4;
}

.mob-menu-container .content-container .lang {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F4F5F9;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #515151;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang ul li {
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang ul li.current-language a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang ul li.current-language a span {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #515151;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .mob-menu-container .content-container .lang ul li a span {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #67579C;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header noMiddle unlogged">
  <div class="mob-menu-container open">
    <div class="menu-container-header">
      <a title="Войти" href="https://example.com" class="login-btn-mobile">Войти</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      <p class="mmenu-heading">Справочная информация</p>
      <div class="box">
        <div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="https://example.com">Текст</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com">Текст</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com">Текст</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com">Текст</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com">Текст</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a class="logout" title="Выйти" href="https://example.com">Выйти</a> </div>
      <p class="mmenu-heading">Поддержка</p>
      <div class="box contacts">
        <a href="tel:0000000">0000000</a>
        <p class="albel">текст</p>
        <p class="albel">текст <span class="forHide">|</span><br> текст</p>
        <p class="albel">текст</p>
      </div>
      <div class="lang">
        <p>Язык: </p>
        <ul>
          <li class="current-language"><a href="https://example.com"><span>UA</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://example.com"><span>RU</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Если прописываю `css`

.header .mob-menu-container {
height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}

и `javascript`

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

То, языковая панель отображается, правда уже с маленьким лагом. Посмотреть можно [по ссылке](https://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/menu.html)
Как эту проблему можно (кроссбраузерно) решить и желательно без скриптов?

Comment: А я наблюдаю проблему еще и в десктопном и в мобильном Firefox.